# Injecting service inside class implementing IEntityTypeConfiguration.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having a hard time injecting a service inside a class that implements IEntityTypeConfiguration. So here is what I have tried so far. The goal I want to do is to have a query filter setup based on the data that I have on ICurrentUserService

```
public class CampaignConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Campaign>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _iCurrentUserService;

    public CampaignConfiguration(ICurrentUserService iCurrentUserService)
    {
        _iCurrentUserService = iCurrentUserService;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("campaigns");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.HasIndex(p => new { p.Id, p.ExternalId });
        ConfigureQueryFilters(builder);
        ConfigureProperties(builder);
        ConfigureRelationships(builder);
    }

    private void ConfigureQueryFilters(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.HasQueryFilter(p => p.DateEnd == null);
        builder.HasQueryFilter(p => _iCurrentUserService.LinkedAgencyIds.Any(agencyId => p.AgencyNo == agencyId));
    }
}
```

Here's what I have on my DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

and I am now getting this error,

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Campaign' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Seems to be that the configuration is not working when I have injected the ICurrenUserService on it.

Comment: I can't understand, why do you use injection inside an IEntityTypeConfiguration class?

Comment: So the goal is to setup a query filter based on what data I have on ICurrentUserService. @mostafakhoramnia do I make sense? or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: So where is this filter you are talking about?
look, as @Dharmeshsharma answered you have to register all IEntityTypeConfiguration inheritances classes for all tables configurations and no need to inject anything here

Comment: I have edited the question @mostafakhoramnia. So before when there's no injected service and no query filters. It is working, but once I have injected the ICurrentUserService, the configuration doesn't work anymore.

Comment: what if you inject ICurrentUserService inside DbContext and write QueryFilter in OnModelCreating? something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: yes, I can do that but it is somehow a bit messy. trying to figure out if there's a way of having it injected directly on a class that implements IEntityTypeConfiguration so it is organize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DI services inside an IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> when using ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly() assembly scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638358/access-di-services-inside-an-ientitytypeconfigurationt-when-using-applyconfigu)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //dynamically load all entity and query type configurations
        var typeConfigurations = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type =>
            (type.BaseType?.IsGenericType ?? false)
                && (type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GutEntityTypeConfiguration<>)
                    || type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GutQueryTypeConfiguration<>)));

        foreach (var typeConfiguration in typeConfigurations)
        {
            var configuration = (IMappingConfiguration)Activator.CreateInstance(typeConfiguration);
            configuration.ApplyConfiguration(modelBuilder);
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

"GutEntityTypeConfiguration" is my Type Configuration so you can use your.

```
public partial class CompanyMasterMap : GutEntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyMaster>
    {
        #region Methods
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CompanyMaster> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(nameof(CompanyMaster));
            builder.HasKey(key => key.ID);
            base.Configure(builder);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Actually the code I have stated above is working but only without the injected service.

Comment: You have to register all Injection. Same code I am using with DI my all Services, Repository, etc.