# How to access interface in IEntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using with code-first in ef core 6. I'm  configuring my entities using fluent api. Each entity has an config class inherited from `IEntityTypeconfiguration`. I'm using `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` instead `ApplyConfiguration<>` because have many entites.
The problem is that you cannot resolve or inject custom interfaces in configuration classes.

Context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly);
 }
```

if i do constructor injection,not trigger in add-migration

```
public class FooConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
 {
    public IFooDomainService _service {get; set;}
    public FooConfiguration (IFooDomainService service)
    {
       _service = service
    }
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        //Not triggering when add-migration because IFooDomainService param is need
        builder.HasData(_service.Create("Foo","Bar"))
    }
}
```

How do I use the interfaces in `IEntityTypeconfiguration`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DI services inside an IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> when using ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly() assembly scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638358/access-di-services-inside-an-ientitytypeconfigurationt-when-using-applyconfigu)

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic it's not. i have many services. i shouldn't send every service as param.

Comment: @OkanKaradag then send service resolver as a parameter =)

Comment: Also what `_service` actually does? I would argue that in general case it is a bad design to do so.

Comment: I'm using ddd. when I'm create entity, i should do depends domain rule and logic so i ensure consistency.

Comment: How configuring EF Model, should depend on domain rules? Just do not create entity in configuring, do it in another method.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv how i do generate seed data without using `builder.HasData`. either way i'm need `IEntityTypeConfiguration`

Comment: It was misunderstood. I already need `HasData` for seed data So I am using `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. The problem is that I can't use `_service` here and there is no alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this class instead of before

```
    public class FooConfiguration:IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData("Foo","Bar")
    }
}
```